# Excluding a file with perl grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I want to go over all of the files in the directory, except for files ending with '.py'.
The line in the existing script is:

```
my @files = sort(grep(!/^(\.|\.\.)$/, readdir($dir_h)));
```

And I want something like:

```
my @files = sort(grep(!/^(\.|\.\.|"*.py")$/, readdir($dir_h)));
```

Can you please help with the exact syntax?

Answer (score 1):

[grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) uses regular expressions, not globs (aka wildcards). The correct syntax is

```
my @files = sort(grep(!/^(\.|\.\.|.*\.py)$/, readdir($dir_h)));
```

or, without the unnecessary parentheses

```
my @files = sort grep ! /^(\.|\.\.|.*\.py)$/, readdir $dir_h;
```

As the parentheses in the regular expression aren't used for capturing, but only for precedence, you can change them to non-capturing:

```
my @files = sort grep ! /^(?:\.|\.\.|.*\.py)$/, readdir $dir_h;
```

You can express the same in many different ways, e.g.

```
/^\.{1,2}$|\.py$/
```

i.e. dot once or twice with nothing around, or `.py` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

perl's build in `grep` is actually very clever - it iterates an array, applying a condition to each element in turn. It sets each element to `$_`.

This condition *can* be a simple regular expression, but it doesn't have to be.

So you can - for example:

```
my @files = grep { -f $_ } readir(DIR);
```

But because `-f` defaults to `$_` you can also:

```
my @files = grep { -f } readdir (DIR);
```

You can also apply a regular expression to `$_`

```
my @files = grep { not m/\.py$/ } readdir (DIR);
```

(Note - this is the same as `not $_ =~ m/\.py$/` - patterns apply to `$_` by default).

So you can do what you want by:

```
my @files = sort grep { not m/\.py$/ and -f } readdir (DIR);
```

Although note - that will work in the current working directory, not for reading a separate path. You can use `readdir` for different directories, but personally I prefer `glob` - because it fills in the path as well:

```
my @files = sort grep { not m/\.py$/ and -f } glob ( "$dir/*" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the directory entries are `files` and then exclude those that end in `.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = "/home/me/somedir";

# good examples in the perldoc:
# perldoc -f readdir
opendir(my $DIR, $dir) || die "Unable to open $dir : $!";

# -f checks that it is a plain file ( perldoc perlfunc )
# !~ means does not match ( perldoc perlre )
# m|\.py$| means a match string that ends in '.py'
my @files = sort grep { -f "$dir/$_" && $_ !~ m|\.py$| } readdir($DIR);
```